# PostgreSQL - Datetime ranges overlap

Tags: postgresql, performance, range-types, gist-index, postgresql-performance

I have a table with datetime fields `start` and `end`. And I have a list of (start, end) items. I need to check which items from the list overlap with data in the table.
The current query looks like this:

```
select br.duration from booking, (
    select tstzrange('2016-09-06 03:45:00+00', '2016-09-06 14:45:00+00') as duration 
    union select tstzrange('2016-09-06 14:45:00+00', '2016-09-06 15:45:00+00') as duration
    -- other items from my list
) as br 
where tstzrange(start, end) && br.duration
```

Are there any other ways to do it? Do you think it will work if I have millions rows in the table and will compare them with hundreds items from the list?

Comment: I think you can relatively easily generate the expected number of rows in a test database, and then check the execution time of your query.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest a couple of important improvements for dealing with a million rows:

```
SELECT br.duration
FROM  (
   VALUES 
      ('[2016-09-06 03:45:00+00, 2016-09-06 14:45:00+00)'::tstzrange)  
    , ('[2016-09-06 14:45:00+00, 2016-09-06 15:45:00+00)')
      -- more items
   ) br(duration)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM booking
   WHERE  tstzrange(ts_start, ts_end) && br.duration
   );
```

- While providing your list of values with the needlessly verbose and expensive form `SELECT ... UNION ...`, make that `UNION ALL`, or Postgres will waste time trying to fold duplicates. And you would only need to declare column name(s) and data type(s) for the first `SELECT` of the `UNION` query.
  But a **`VALUES`** expression is simpler and faster. Or provide an array `tstzrange[]` and use `unnest()`:

  - [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)
- The query you have would return one row for every overlapping row in `booking`, while you probably want each overlapping value from the list *once*, most likely. You could add `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to get unique rows, but that would still be a waste of time. An **`EXISTS`** semi-join is one of the much simpler and cheaper alternatives for your case: Each row from `duration` is returned exactly once if an overlapping entry is found and Postgres can stop looking further for this row.
- The query would still be slow without index support. Create a functional GiST or [**SP-GiST index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spgist-builtin-opclasses.html#SPGIST-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE). The latter probably performing best:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX booking_ts_range_idx on booking USING spgist (tstzrange(ts_start, ts_end));
  ```

Related:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)
- [Native way of performing this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/native-way-of-performing-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)
- [Help with adding a time filter to Postgres query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126213/help-with-adding-a-time-filter-to-postgres-query/126497#126497)
- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524) (incl. SP-GiST index example and benchmark comparing alternatives)

Comment: In my experience using `overlaps` with two timestamp columns seems to be (slightly) faster then using a range type. It's probably worth a try